# How to Parse values from some posts to a object id in a different class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a connection of two classes in Parse.com via Pointer.

I have one class which is called `magazia` and I put some rows inside.

Also I have a class which is called "Events" which has a *magaziaid* column which is Pointer to class `magazia`.

I want to make a post in Events with a specific objectId of the other class ("magaziaid")  from a form.

So I have this code for now:

```
function saveJobApp(objParseFile) {

        var jobApplication = new Parse.Object("events");
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
        var magaziid = "2xOhgyX0BU";



        jobApplication.set("image", objParseFile);
        jobApplication.set("name", name);
        jobApplication.set("description", description);
        jobApplication.set("magaziaid", this.magaziid.id); //breakpoint

        jobApplication.save(null, {
            success: function(gameScore) {
            },
            error: function(gameScore, error) {
                // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
            }
        });
        //var objectId = jobApplication.getObjectId();
        // objectId = document.getElementById("objID").innerHTML;
        // console.log(objectId);

    }


    $('#submitId').on("click", function(e) {
        var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
        var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
        var name = file.name; //This does *NOT* need to be a unique name

        var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
        console.log("Done");

        parseFile.save().then(
            function() {
                saveJobApp(parseFile);
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        );
    });

});
```

That i'm trying to put the objectId copied from the "magazia" class, but i get an error, **"Failed to create object with error code: Undefined"**
What is my mistake here?
How can i pass the object id of a row from "magazia" class and put it on the pointer of the class "events" ???

Thanks in advance!

Update 1. in //breakpoint  i have also tried those different codes

```
jobApplication.set("magaziaid", {__type: "Pointer", className: "events", objectId: magaziid});
```

and this one

```
jobApplication.set("magaziaid", magaziid);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer value should be a `magazia` object and not an id. Do the following and it should work.

```
var magaziaObject = new Parse.Object("magazia");
// add anything you want to magaziaObject
// like magaziaObject.id, magaziaObject.name, etc.
// and then save the magaziaObject in your events (jobApplication) object
jobApplication.set("magaziaid", magaziaObject);
```